# Getting user info, e.g, title, department in onelogin user API

Tags: onelogin

I'm using the Onelogin [user API](https://developers.onelogin.com/api-docs/1/users/get-users/) interface to retrieve profile information for use in my application. I require the fields of `Department` and `Title` in the response, but this is not returned by default.

I did find a hack to replicate the info in `Custom Fields`, since all information present under `Custom Fields` is sent in the response of the API query.

Is there any other way to mention that these required fields need to be sent in the API response?

#### Sample Response:

```
'data':[
     {
        'status':1,
        'distinguished_name':None,
        'password_changed_at': '2016-09-21T12:09:03.021         Z',
        'updated_at': '2016-09-27T08:52:00.179         Z',
        'directory_id':None,
        'invalid_login_attempts':None,
        'locked_until':None,
        'openid_name':'ash###',
        'id':27046681,
        'invitation_sent_at':'2016-08-09T06:53:57.334         Z',
        'manager_ad_id':None,
        'custom_attributes':{
           'city':'San Francisco'
           'dept':'Engineering'    
        },
        'role_id':None,
        'last_login': '2016-09-27T08:52:00.140         Z',
        'email':'ash###########',
        'username':'ash###########',
        'samaccountname':None,
        'firstname':'Ash###',
        'lastname':'',
        'activated_at': '2016-08-11T06:35:19.147         Z',
        'userprincipalname':None,
        'phone':'',
        'member_of':None,
        'created_at': '2016-08-09T06:53:57.360         Z',
        'locale_code':None,
        'group_id':None,
        'external_id':None,
        'notes':None
     }
```

Answer (score 1):

Engineering has completed your requested enhancement and these fields should be available now.